# Search only approved items using KeywordQuery

Tags: 2007, search-scope, keywordquery

We have approval workflow for document library & content approval column was set to yes for it.
We have used KeywordQuery on the library by creating separate scope.
We want to display only approved items in search result for that we have set ApprovalStatus property to Zero in scope rule.
but even after adding this propert we are getting pending documents in search result.
Also after adding the property ApprovalStatus = 0 ,Item Count shows "error" as its value instead of count.

Pls let me know how to show only Approved items in search result.

Answer (score 0):

ows_ModerationStatus is the crawled property you are looking for. In my environment, it is not mapped to a metadata property, which is what the keyword search uses. Here is the msdn link to manage metadata properties: [MSDN metadata properties](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621097%28v=office.14%29.aspx). Check to make sure the mapping from moderation status to approvalstatus is set up.

Comment: I did mapping of Approvalstatus with ows_ModerationStatus.
but by adding ApprovalStatus = 0 in scope rule still it is not working.Can you please tell me can I use this property in KeywordQuery & how to use it?

Comment: Did you run a full crawl after setting up the ApprovalStatus metadata property?